# Convert NSAttributedString to string and back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have NSString and I need to make NSAttributedString.

NSString is something like:

```
bvcx b vcxbcvx bcxvbcxv bvx xbc bcvx bxcv bcxv bcxv bcxv bcvx bcvx bcxvbcvx bvc bcvx bxcv{
NSFont = "\"LucidaGrande 24.00 pt. P [] (0x108768a80) fobj=0x108788880, spc=7.59\"";
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0.05, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

It's NSAttributedString in UTF-8. Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for `NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"foo"];`?

Comment: Nope, I need formatted nsattributestring. Thx for interest.

Comment: Then you can use `NSMutableAttributedString` and add whatever kind of attributes you would like to.

Comment: Just use `NSAttributedString initWithString:attributes:`.

Comment: Where did your `NSString` contents come from?

Comment: It's UTF-8 NSAttributedString. Something like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nsattributedstring].

Comment: That's the same as logging the attributed string. That's for debugging only.

Comment: An NSString isn't UTF8.  Your string appears to be the output of some sort of word processor program (possibly even the `description` output for an NSAttributedString -- I've never seen that), and you need to understand that format to handle it (if it's not already an attributed string).  There's no "automatic" mechanism in Objective-C to perform that translation.

Comment: Do this:  Set up a test label in your app -- something you can assign to and view.  Assign the source variable for the above string (without modifiying it in any way) to `myTestLabel.attributedText`.  See if the string appears with its format.

Comment: Or, alternatively, do `NSLog(@"The class is %s", object_getClassName(myFunnyString));`, and see what class name is printed.

Comment: maybe this could help you:
[enter link description here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105736/parsing-text-from-plist-to-nsattributedstring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You said you created your input string from an existing `NSAttributedString` like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nsattributedstring]
```

The `%@` format specifier sends the `description` message to the `nsattributedstring` object.  The `description` method is not designed to produce a string that can be easily converted back to an `NSAttributedString` object.  It is designed to help programmers debug their code.

The process of converting an object to a string, or an array of bytes, so that it can be converted back to an object later, is called **serialization**.  Using `%@` or the `description` method is generally not a good way to perform serialization.  If you really want to deserialize the string created by the `description` method, you'll have to write your own parser.  As far as I know, there is no API for that.

Instead, Cocoa provides a system designed to serialize and deserialize objects.  Objects that can be serialized using this system conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. `NSAttributedString` objects conform to `NSCoding`.  So try serializing your original attributed string this way:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:nsattributedstring];
```

Save `data` (which is non-human-readable binary, not UTF-8) wherever you need to.  When you need to recreate the attributed string, do this:

```
NSAttributedString *fancyText = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

**If you are programming for OS X** (*not* iOS), you have an alternative.  You can turn an attributed string into RTF (rich text format), which is fairly human-readable, using the [`RTFFromRange:documentAttributes:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-BAJEEGDC) (which omits attachments) or the [`RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-BAJEFCGI) (which includes attachments).  Then you can turn the RTF data back into an attributed string using `initWithRTF:documentAttributes:` or `initWithRTFD:documentAttributes:`.  These methods are not available on iOS.

**If you are programming for iOS 7.0 or later**, you can use `-dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:` or `fileWrapperFromRange:documentAttributes:error:` to convert the attributed string to RTF/RTFD.  You need to set `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute` to `NSRTFTextDocumentType` or `NSRTFDTextDocumentType` in the document attributes.  Use `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` or `initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:` to convert back to an `NSAttributedString`.  These methods are part of the [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thx for reply. I know about NSCoding, but I need to get UTF-8 of NSAttributedString because I'm writing string into UTF-8 xml file. Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: @MichalJuriJurník: There is no such thing as “UTF-8 of NSAttributedString”. An NSAttributedString is a string plus attributes; you can encode any string as UTF-8 data, but you still have to serialize the attributes separately, and then deserialize/decode them both and put them back together on the other end. Use the RTF methods; they're designed for this.

Comment: When I tried, I got this error - How to resolve it -      [NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf078af0            *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf078af0'

Comment: @Dinesh You need to post this as a new question.  Include your code and the details of the string you're trying to serialize.