# Using librtf with Objective C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, rtf

I'm using an API that returns an RTF formatted string that I need to be able to view and edit on an iOS application.

I was hoping to use the [librtf](http://librtf.sourceforge.net/) libary to parse the RTF string as an NSAttributedString.  I'm new to mixing C/C++ with Objective-C.  Given a subclass of UITextView, say RTFTextView, how can I include the implementation to parse the string into an NSAttributedString, and back to an rtfFormattedString after editing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing text from plist to NSAttributedString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105736/parsing-text-from-plist-to-nsattributedstring)

Comment: How is it a duplicate? the rtf tags I need to parse through are generated from a Windows rtf editor.  The link you've provided has a custom markdown thats alot more simplified than a rtf markdown.  Am I wrong in saying this?

Comment: He's also said that "I am aware that solutions are available for parsing RTF and HTML, but this is overkill for my needs - plus I'd like the text to be easily written by hand.".  I need the lightweight RTF parser that can get me an NSAttributedString from the RTF markdown string returned from the server, and generate the RTF markdown string to send back to the server once the user is done editting.

Comment: I'd argue that libRTF is overkill if solutions exist that are easy and painless.  The answers in that question are meant to be a starting point for you, not complete solutions.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is getting downvoted? I had assumed using a library that would be able to parse RTF natively would be easier, rather than modifying MGMushParser to parse RTF into NSAttibutedStrings (thus creating a problem when an RTF file includes tables and drawings).